# Getting Position in jQuery Animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am animating one image(i.e)scaling a image like

```
$('#img').animate({height:'300px','width':'20px'},2000);
```

i need to get the current height of the image during the animation. i tried step property. But its printing so many points which is unrelated to animation.

Any Idea

Answer (score 2):

There's a step option in the animate function that allows for callbacks during the animation. In that callback you can request the position and do what you want with it.

http://jsfiddle.net/aYVUE/

Answer (score 0):

```
var pos = $('#img').position();
alert(pos.top + ', ' + pos.left);
```

See [this](http://api.jquery.com/position/) link.